# Illegal Variable Name/Number when Passing in Python List

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to run SQL statements through Python on a list.
By passing in a list, in this case date. Since i want to run multiple SELECT SQL queries and return them.
I've tested this by passing in integers, however when trying to pass in a date I am getting ORA-01036 error. Illegal variable name/number. I'm using an Oracle DB.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
date = ["'01-DEC-21'", "'02-DEC-21'"]

sql = "select * from table1 where datestamp = :date"

for item in date:
    cursor.execute(sql,id=item)
    res=cursor.fetchall()
    print(res)
```

Any suggestions to make this run?

Comment: use IN instead of =, = is for one value and IN is for list

Comment: @AhmedSunny thanks for this info. It is a larger table and sometimes takes longer to parse through using IN vs. running one at a time

Comment: Read the cx_Oracle documentation [Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause) which has some general solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't name a bind variable `date`, it's an illegal name. Also your named variable in `cursor.execute` should match the bind variable name. Try something like:

```
sql = "select * from table1 where datestamp = :date_input"

for item in date:
  cursor.execute(sql,date_input=item)
  res=cursor.fetchall()
  print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some recommendation and warnings to your *approach*:

- you *should not* depend on your default `NLS` date setting, while binding a `String` (e.g. `"'01-DEC-21'"`) to a `DATE` column. (You probably need also remone one of the quotes).
- You should ommit to fetch data in a *loop* if you can fetch them in one query (using an `IN` list)
- use prepared statement

**Example**

```
date = ['01-DEC-21', '02-DEC-21']
```

This generates the query *that uses bind variables* for your input list

```
in_list = ','.join([f" TO_DATE(:d{ind},'DD-MON-RR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')" for ind, d in enumerate(date)])

sql_query = "select * from table1 where datestamp in ( " + in_list + " )"
```

The `sql_query` generate is

```
select * from table1 where datestamp in 
(  TO_DATE(:d0,'DD-MON-RR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'), TO_DATE(:d1,'DD-MON-RR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') )
```

Note that the `IN`list contains one bind variable for each member of your input list.

Note also the usage of `to_date`  with explicite mask and fixing the language to avoid problems with interpretation of the month abbreviation. (e.g.  `ORA-01843: not a valid month`)

Now you can use the query to fetch the data in one pass

```
cur.prepare(sql_query)
cur.execute(None, date)
res = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks for this input. I've modified and now i am getting `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`

Comment: Since Oracle has a [statement cache](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#statement-caching) there may be little benefit to an explicit `prepare()`

Comment: This is true and also the *cursor cache* works fine @ChristopherJones. So in this simple example there will be no *visible* effect. Anyway IMO the *recommendation* to use *prepared statements* in a *large scale* applications still holds.